# netstandard system.collections.specialized.dll has 2171 unexpected token errors

Tags: c#, .net-standard-2.0

My system.collections.specialized.dll is corrupted. Seems like it should be a simple matter to uninstall and reinstall it, but I have not found how to do it.

I tried to reply to the comment but my edit timed out.
In Visual Studio the Blazor project I was working on the Error List showed the 2171 errors found, all 'unexpected token'. I tried uninstalling net-standard (it is 2.03 but I could not create a tag) using NuGet. I looked in the GAC but don't know enough to mess with the files there. I deleted all the bin and obj directories of the project and recompiled. Nothing helped. This morning the project compiles without errors.

Comment: _"is corrupted"_ why do you think so?

Comment: In Visual Studio the Blazor project I was working on the Error List showed the 2171 errors found, all 'unexpected token' .

Comment: Did you accidentally open the .dll file into the text editor, or add it as a source file in your project?

Comment: Honestly, the chances a DLL magically became corrupted is pretty small. Can you post the code?

Comment: I think the file did get opened in the editor while debugging. At one point I got a message asking if I wanted to normalize line endings. I declined and closed things but it was probably too late. But regardless of how it happened, I was interested in how to fix it. Then it magically cured itself and I still don't know how to recover if such a thing happens again.